# Making a RESTful OData API for a non-database application

Tags: .net, rest, odata, restful-architecture

I have an existing large desktop C# application which I would like to expose some data from (mostly for other local applications, though possibly network or cloud applications too), ideally in a queryable/filterable REST format such as OData.  (I like the idea of clients being able to do LINQ queries easily.)

However the data that I want to provide is a mixture of persistent business objects and non-persistent status objects (things like timers, counters, and other statistics).  And it uses custom persistence, not a database.

Most of the examples I can find for OData or other actually-RESTful systems (ones that do HATEOS and aren't just being RPC in disguise) seem to assume that there's a database in behind, which is not the case here.  Or things like WebAPI which only give you the minimal HTTP routing and require you to implement queries etc manually.

(And even if the application did use a database for the persistent objects, that doesn't help with trying to present the non-persistent objects.)

I recognise that I'll probably have to put in some kind of translation layer between the "real" object model of the application and the model exposed to the REST services (since some of the properties are stored in different places or different formats internally), but again I'm not sure how to integrate that with a REST framework.

Some of the properties would be updating very frequently, while others quite seldom, so I would like things like ETags and Last-Modified to Just Work but it seems ugly to try to maintain both object trees.  (It also seems a bit ugly to just resync on demand from the API though, and I'm not sure which is worse.)

(The .NET OData libraries seem to require Entity Framework, which in turn seems to require a database, not just an object tree.)

Is there a way to make this just work, or is it sufficiently complex that using WebAPI and building everything from the ground up is really the only option?

Comment: I think your title is misleading.  The title appears to be asking if a rest api MUST have a database (answer: of course not); the question body seems to be asking if there's a simple way to do that given your constraints....

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Better?